# Why can't protected methods be called with symbol to proc?

Tags: ruby

Given the following class:

```
class Foo
  def a
    dup.tap { |foo| foo.bar }
  end

  def b
    dup.tap(&:bar)
  end

  protected

  def bar
    puts 'bar'
  end
end
```

It seems like both `Foo#a` and `Foo#b` should be equivalent, but they're not:

```
> Foo.new.a
bar
 => #<Foo:0x007fe64a951ab8>

> Foo.new.b
NoMethodError: protected method `bar' called for #<Foo:0x007fe64a940a88>
```

Is there a reason for this? Is this a bug?

Tested on Ruby 2.2.3p173

Comment: This is a great question. Let's hope someone can enlighten us.

Comment: Good question indeed. Only difference I can see is that you call `bar` on a local variable in the first block, but call it on no variable with a proc. Still, curious to know if there's a good reason for this.

Comment: Tested without the `foo` variable but still same thing. I think this must have to do with how procs are called, although I'd imagine these two methods should output equivalent results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by noting that in Ruby, as you probably know, in a method `a` declared on a class `Foo`, I can invoke protected methods on *any instance of* `Foo`.

How does Ruby determine whether we're in a method declared on class `Foo` though?  To understand this, we'll have to dig into the internals of method invocation.  I'll be using examples from version 2.2 of MRI, but presumably the behavior and implementation are the same in other versions (I'd love to see results from testing this on JRuby or Rubinious, though).

Ruby does this in [`rb_call0`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/vm_eval.c#311).  As the comment suggests, `self` is used to determine whether we can call protected methods.  `self` is retrieved in [`rb_call`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/vm_eval.c#582) from the current thread's call frame info.  Then, in [`rb_method_call_status`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/vm_eval.c#555), we check that this value of `self` is of the same class on which a protected method is defined.

Blocks confuse the issue somewhat.  Remember that local variables in a Ruby method are captured by any block declared in that method.  This means that in the block, `self` is the same `self` on which the method was invoked.  Let's look at an example:

```
class Foo
    def give_me_a_block!
        puts "making a block, self is #{self}"
        Proc.new do
            puts "self in block0 is #{self}"
       end
    end
end

proc = Foo.new.give_me_a_block!

proc.call
```

Running this, we see the same instance of `Foo` is the same at all levels, even though we called the proc from a completely different object.

So, now we understand why it's possible to call a protected method on another instance of the same class from within a block in a method.

Now let's look at why a proc created with `&:bar` can't do this.  When we place an `&` sign before a method argument we do two things: instruct ruby to pass this argument as a block, and instruct it to call `to_proc` on it.

This means invoking the method `Symbol#to_proc`.  This method is implemented in C, but when we invoke a C method, the pointer to `self` on the current frame becomes the receiver of that C method -- in this case, it becomes the symbol `:bar`.  So we're looking at the instance of `foo` we got *as though we are in a method of class Symbol*, and we can't invoke a protected method.

That's a mouthful, but hopefully it makes enough sense.  Let me know if you have any suggestions as to how I might improve it!